# WooCommerce, categories for product variations

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, categories, product-variations

Is there a way to assign unique categories to individual product variations? For example a site that sells baby bibs, in pink or blue. You'd have one product (the bib) with two variations (colours). You might also have two categories, Boy Bibs and Girl Bibs.

Could the pink bib variation be assigned to the Girl Bibs category, whilst the blue bib variation is assigned to the Boy Bibs category? The only difference between the two bibs is the colour so it makes sense to have them setup as product variations.

Previously the client handled this in OpenCart by duplicating products to assign them to their respective category which seemed the wrong way to do it.

**EDIT:**

I suppose this scenario is a bit like 'six of one, half a dozen of the other' - neither way is wrong or right and the answer might come down to how the client wants to handle orders that are generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion that is not possible as the product (the main product) is bound to one or multiple categories, variations are linked to the main product. So either do as with OpenCart - duplicate the product remove the unneeded variations.

Comment: I went with duplicating products. I believe the main reason she did this was so that she could have the image of the girl bib (pink) shown on the product page rather than the boy bib (blue)